# Calculate Bounce Rate SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate the Bounce Rate of pages in SQL Server in a table with Audit Data from Sharepoint.

```
ItemId  UserId  DocLocation  Occurred
1       1       Home.aspx    2016-08-02 13:39:41
1       2       Home.aspx    2016-08-02 13:40:07
2       1       Other.aspx   2016-08-02 13:40:16
3       1       Items.aspx   2016-08-02 13:40:17
2       2       Other.aspx   2016-08-02 13:40:11
```

`ItemId` is the id of the page, `DocLocation` the location of the page and `Occurred` when the user goes into the page.

To calculate the bounce rate we have to divide the number of bounces between the total number of visits.

A Bounce happens when an user leaves the page in less than 5 seconds.

This should be the results for that table:

```
ItemId  Bounces  Visits  BounceRate(Bounces/Visits)
1       1        2       0.5
2       1        2       0.5
3       0        1       0
```

I want to count a bounce calculating how much passes since the user performs the check until the user makes a visit to another page. If that time is less than 5 seconds, it would be counted as a bounce.

I'm making a stored procedure that execute the query to show the bounce rate of each page, but this doesn´t work.

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN (DATEDIFF(second, @Occurred, 
                                 (SELECT TOP 1 a.Occurred
                                  FROM [AuditPages] a
                                  WHERE a.UserId = @userId 
                                    AND a.Occurred > @occurred
                                  ORDER BY a.Occurred ASC))) < 30 
              THEN 1.0
              ELSE 0.0 
        END) / COUNT(@itemId)
```

Someone knows how i can calculate this Bounce Rate?

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: please provide some sample data and show expected result

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: What is `the Bounce Rate of pages on SQL SERVER`?

Comment: We need some actual information to be able to help. Try this as a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I edited the message and hope it is clearer than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using row_number for this type of sequenced problem. The query below gives the desired result. I find performance with CTEs can sometimes be problematic with larger tables and you may need to convert to a temp table. You might consider using milliseconds if there is a chance you would want to use 4.5 seconds or such in the future.

```
declare @bounce_seconds int = 5;

with audit_cte as (

    select  *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserId order by Occurred) row_num
    from    AuditPages
    --order by UserId,row_num
)
select      a.ItemId, sum(a.bounce) Bounces, count(1) Visits, sum(a.bounce)/convert(float, count(1)) BounceRate
from        (
            select      a1.ItemId, datediff(s,a1.Occurred, a2.Occurred) elapsed, case when datediff(s,a1.Occurred, a2.Occurred) < @bounce_seconds then 1 else 0 end bounce
            from        audit_cte a1
            left join   audit_cte a2
                        on  a2.UserId = a1.UserId
                        and a2.row_num = a1.row_num + 1
            --order by  a1.UserId, a1.row_num
            ) a
group by    a.ItemId
order by    a.ItemId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ItemId,COUNT(1) VISITS,SUM(BOUNCE_IND) BOUNCE, cast(SUM(BOUNCE_IND) as decimal(5,2))/cast(COUNT(1) as decimal(5,2)) BOUNCE_RATE
FROM (
    Select 
        UserID,
        ItemID,
        DocLocation,
        Occurred as Entry_time,
        Lead(Occurred,1) Over (Partition by Userid order by Occurred) Exit_time,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ss,Occurred,Lead(Occurred,1) Over (Partition by Userid order by Occurred)) <= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END BOUNCE_IND
    FROM Web_Data_Sample
) TBL GROUP BY ItemId
```